# How to use cascade update on PK in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

```
ALTER EMPLOYEE
DROP CONSTRAINT MGR_SSN
 Change all SSN           ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

When an employee’s SSN is updated
- then propagate that change to all pertinent FKs

Link to DB:  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wCwvN6pFq2cXvfuE57QTum/0#&togetherjs=8aityz4DAt

Answer (score 0):

If you need to update a primary key, your DB design is not good.

That being said, it is possible to add a foreign key to a table with the constraint you have given. See below (I have added a `ON DELETE SET NULL`).

I repeat: I recommend you review your DB design.

```
ALTER TABLE Employee
ADD FOREIGN KEY (Mgr_SSN) REFERENCES Employee(SSN) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Comment: This doesn't work as it needs to update all FKs like MGR_SSN,SUPER_SSN,ESSN

Comment: And obviously, you can't copy the query and change table and/or field name yourself ...